# How to prevent other people using the specific IP address?

Tags: networking, router, ip

I have a local PC that required a specific fixed IP. But it is frequently that other PC or mobile devices are using that specific IP. I have tried to assign that IP to the PC mac address on my router. But still, it doesn't prevent other PC or devices from connecting with that specific IP address. The only thing it does help is that, if I repeating connecting & disconnecting that PC network, it will eventually take over to that specific IP address.

Is there anyway that I can better prevent other people from connecting into the network with that specific IP address?

Comment: In the router you can set a dhcp range of addresses, once this is done  you can manually set your ip address on each PC to use a ip outside this range, this will avoid ip collisions.

Comment: If your router isnt assigning IP addresses properly you can disable its DHCP server and rin one on another device thats always-on.  A DHCP server does not need to exist on the router - but unless you know exactly what you are doing you should only run 1 dhcp server per network.

Comment: On that note, if you turn off your router are devices still being assigned IP addresses? If so you may have a rogue DHCP server - and shutting it off could fiz the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean DHCP, then there are 2 possibilities:

1. Reserve your MAC in the DHCP list, but as you say, it does not seem to work, therefore it is a bug.
2. Ensure the DHCP pool is less than the subnet width, then apply a static IP address to you PC which is outwith that range. ie, for 192.168.0.0/24, set a range of 192.168.0.20 - 192.168.0.50, then configure 192.168.0.70 on your PC.

However, ultimately, there isn't anything you can do to ensure it will not happen since people can apply whatever IP address they want if they have permission. All you can do is reduce the possibility.

Comment: Your answer is substantially correct but your last paragraph is incorrect   You can do mac filtering to prevent this.

Comment: Mac filtering does not always exist, and usually only over wifi, not via cable connection.

Comment: MAC filtering does not always exist - true.  MAC filtering is common on managed switches.

Comment: My answer is correct. If the pc needs to be connected, and the user has permissions, then they can configure an already used IP address. My answer is correct, stop trying to find pointless holes in it.

Comment: Your answer can be modified to be correct.  Were I looking for holes in your answer (rather then just correcting incorrect statements) I'd fault the answer for ignoring out the possibility of another competing dhcp server. When people point out mistakes in my answer I typically modify it to make it more correct/canonical including an acknowledgement to the person that pointed out the flaw/limits.

Comment: Laughable. Ultimately you cannot prevent it, end of story. Down mod if you want.

Answer (score 0):

> have tried to assign that IP to the PC mac address on my router. But
> still, it doesn't prevent other PC or devices from connecting with
> that specific IP address.

It is quite possible your router does not provide DHCP Address Reservation as numerous routers do not. My current router does not even though its predecessor did.

So then your options are more limited.

1. I have a main machine (Windows) that I connect to and synchronize files with. I give this machine a Static IP on my network. This machine is always ON so no other device can grab its IP address.
2. I found my phones were constantly changing IP addresses and mucking up my orderly plan, so I gave my phones Static IP addresses as well.

The result (1 and 2 together) means very little change in my network and most devices use plain DHCP.